# How to make Mypy recognize frozen dataclasses as Hashable

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy, python-dataclasses

So creating effectively hashable dataclasses with `frozen=True` is great, but it breaks some of my ability to typecheck code I write since mypy doesn't seem to automagically recognize frozen dataclasses as instances of `Hashable`. This makes sense of course, since I haven't explicitly extended that class (it would be amazing if it could infer), but has anyone out there found an elegant solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: Can you make an not working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking deeper my issue was actually a variance issue due to working with lists of such dataclasses. The support is there, just be mindful of variance  :)

In my cases using `Sequence[Hashable]` instead of `List[Hashable]` in my type annotations appeased mypy. Turns out that since list elements are mutable they are invariant whereas sequences are covariant. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance